# Pygame: pygame.display.flip() slows down game considerably

Tags: pygame

I'm currently working on a Super Mario Bros clone and when I run either `pygame.display.flip()` or `pygame.display.update()`, my fps gets capped at about 20fps.

Even an empty main loop with just a `clock.tick(60)` and `update()` with nothing being drawn gives the same result.

When I remove `pygame.display.update()` I get 60 fps with my game running all calculations.

```
import pygame as pg

class Main():
        
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((1000, 1000))
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()

    def main_loop(self):
        while True:
            self.clock.tick(60)
            print(self.clock.get_fps())
            pg.display.flip()

main = Main()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main.main_loop()
```

Higher screen sizes result in lower framerates.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise we can't properly analyze the program.

Comment: Does the new, shortened example run with 20 FPS on your computer? It should work fine, i.e. run with 60 FPS (only the events need to be handled every frame).

Comment: Yeah 1000x1000 gives me about 15 fps.

Comment: Please provide more information such as the operating system, the hardware and the Python and pygame versions. How do you run the program?

Comment: I'm using mac os x with python 2.7.15 and pygame 1.9.3. I use vscode ide and run it in there or by using the command line.

Comment: I don't think this should be an answer as I doubt this is a valid solution for you, but have you tried using the `pygame.FULLSCREEN` parameter in the `.set_mode()` call? That tends to speed up graphics quite a bit. Also, always `.convert()` all your sprites/images (and `.convert_alpha()` for sprites that have transparency).

Comment: Better ask the devs as well. You can reach them on the mailing list: https://www.pygame.org/wiki/info

Comment: Maybe try removing the FPS clock cap, this might allow it to run freely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Higher screen sizes result in lower framerates.

Of course, so if you don't have a super fast computer, consider reducing the size of your window.

Also, I think 1000x1000 is quite large for most of the screens... So try to reduce the size of your game, for example 900x500, or 640x480, then use the tag [`pygame.SCALED`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) in addition of `pygame.FULLSCREEN` to resize the game window to your current screen size.

> I'm using [...] pygame 1.9.3.

Consider updating your `pygame` version - When I updated `pygame 1.9.6` to `pygame 2.0.1`, I litteraly doubled my framerate. (+ `pygame 2.0.0` and newest releases fix tons of bugs, and add tons of new possibilities)

But if you want a high resolution and a good speed, I think `pygame` isn't enough. If you want to create games in general, consider using [`Unity`](https://unity.com) for example.